# mv: cannot stat "filename" no such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, docker, mv

I'm using the following

```
sudo docker exec -w /home/Docker1 Docker_1 ls -S | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "$n.txt"; done
```

command to execute a sorting/renaming command inside a docker container (which uses alpine) however it fails witht he following error

> mv: cannot stat "filename" no such file or directory"

and I see no reasonable reason why this should be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipeline doesn't run under docker.

```
sudo docker exec -w /home/Docker1 Docker_1 ls -S    # Runs "docker" as root and then calls "ls -S" in Docker's context
cat -n                                              # Runs in your local user's context (not root, not docker)
while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "$n.txt"; done        # Also in your local user's context
```

Were you expecting to rename the files inside the docker container? Perhaps this (but I can't test it). Remove `echo` when you are comfortable it will do what you want:

```
sudo docker exec -w /home/Docker1 Docker_1 sh -c '
    n=1; ls -S | while IFS= read -r f; do echo mv -f "$f" "$n.txt"; n=$((n+1)); done
'
```

Comment: Why did you remove the counter instead of `cat -n`?

Comment: `ls -S` orders by size. I don't want to dig out a `find -printf | sort -z | cut -zf2-` loop to order the files like that when `ls -S` will do

Comment: This works however withinn a script setting it shoots out this
`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`
Which I understand means it is not finding bash, correct? Either because it doesn't exist int his image or because i need to find its ID?

Comment: @Falsey what if you use `sh` instead of `bash`?